# How can I set a breakpoint for a button click using ollydbg?

Tags: ollydbg

How can I set a breakpoint for a button click using ollydbg?

i am trying to disable a button click on game client, so i want to set break point to catch the button click event.
is that possible to happen with ollydbg?

Comment: [This][1] thread will probably contain the answer.


  [1]: http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3288/how-can-i-set-a-breakpoint-for-a-button-click

Answer (score 7):

let application make window and buttons then pause it.

in ollyDBG 1 :

- go to `view > windows`
- select your button.
- right click and select `Message breakpoint on ClassProc`
- in `Messages:` select `202 WM LBUTTONUP`
- select `Break on all windows with same title`
- select `Pause program: On message`
- select `Log WinProc arguments: Never`

in ollyDBG 1 or 2 :

- go to `view > windows`
- select your button.
- right click and select `Conditional breakpoint... Shift+F2`
- type `[ESP+8]==WM_LBUTTONUP` as your condition and run program

Answer (score 3):

well, depends,
if this program does not have any kind of protection against listing the names of the libraries functions and is not java, it's actually pretty simple.

Method A (Better Approach)

> 1º Start debugging the process and let it load
>
> 2º Find out looking in the program imports if it uses User32.dll
>   (probably does maybe not direcly)
>
> 3º Go to OllyDbg and go to Names using Ctrol+N (use this for guide
>   http://www.ollydbg.de/quickst.htm)
>
> 4º Sort by name and type RegisterClass** (it will be a export)
>
> 5º put a breakpoint on all these names using F2
>
> 6º Click on the button

7º You'll break on the message handling, you will need to step foward a bit

thats it

Method B (Lazy Method and less chance of success)

> 1º Start debbuging the program and let it run normally clicking F9
>
> 2º let the program and olly maxized and in front
>
> 3º pause the program then click ALT+F9 or CTROL+F9
>
> 4º Click the button and hope for a break
>
> 5º The program will (may)break on the Return of the button function,
>   you probably will have to trace back to get on the code

Have fun!