# Can't find “referenced string” in OllyDBG

Tags: string, reverse-engineering, ollydbg

So I am trying to reverse a program and crack it but I am not able to find any of the Strings through searching for "referenced Strings" or "binary Strings", I am new to OllyDBG and I don't know a lot about it, which is why this is driving me crazy. I'd like to know how or where I can find the Strings then or if there is another method of finding a given Assembly Line where I could start.

Thank you already :)

Edit: If you need any more information, just ask and I'll deliver it.

Already asked in ReverseEngineering Stackexchange but it seems like nobody there knows or has the time to answer.

Answer (score 7):

searching for `All referenced strings` only show you some function that push address of string but it cant find the address when calculate the address before.

here is a good idea:

press `Alt + M` and press `Ctrl + B` and search. it will find any string.

and then select the memory and use memory break-point for selected memory.

Answer (score 0):

In OllyDBG it is not egal where you do the search. If you search in memory dum window, it will search in only one page. But if you search on memory pages window, it will run through all the pages looking for your string. Also, try searching for utf16 chars.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the right module `Alt+E` where the strings should be and you still could not find, the program could have hid it as an anti debugging measure, you may try to track it down by setting breakpoints on Symbolic Names `Ctrol+N`(which may be hid too) or try using the [button method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24138087/how-can-i-set-a-breakpoint-for-a-button-click-using-ollydbg/26540612#26540612) (which is very bad)